# get the real true external IP even with VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, ip

I am running a server software on my PC.  It has a VPN software running.  The internet connection is wired to a router (sometimes wireless).

I have a PHP script that gets the external IP correctly when the VPN is switched off. But not when the VPN is on.

So is it possible for the server software to get the real IP? As the software is running on the computer whos external IP I am seeking. I’m thinking of a `.bat` file or VBScript function to do this

Is it possible without switching of vpn and changing any router settings?

Comment: You would have find a way to bypass the VPN, maybe with a specific routing statement.

Comment: Properly configure VPN in private mode makes this not possible.  Unless your willing to configure your VPN to leak that information what you want will not likely be possible

Answer (score -1):

If you query an external server, such as Google, it will return the IP address to with which you've connected, or, a proxy server that brokered the query on your system's behalf.  This may be suitable for your purposes; Your mileage may vary.

[What Is My IP](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&site=&source=hp&q=what+is+my+ip&oq=what+is+my+ip)

Comment: got it in one.  The vpn software is used to connect to the intenet so php scripts stored on my VPS server will report the external IP set by VPN, which is not the actual IP.   I thought that the PC can know its own external IP as maybe it can bypass the VPN or not use the VPN by getting the IP locally somehow